# MySQL Database synch up with two database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, data-binding

We have a problem due to a issue with android application, which is some part of the mobile app goes to live and some parts goes to QA. so as a workaround for the time being we have made the QA and Live to be the same copies of DB. so in both database say we have USER & SCHOOL table for example, and android application signup form referrers to QA User table and School entry form refers to Live School table. so this is the problem due to the bug and we need to synch both Database when a User And School is created, We need to add the related School to QA database, School table and Related User to live server User table.

I hope i explained the issue clearly, so i am trying to find a way to synch these two tables in both database when a transaction happen.

In our next android app, this will be fixed. till then, the user's who have the current buggy app and will be using without updating we need to find a way to fix.

**UPDATE:
Please note QA and Live Database is on the same server.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need some kind of MySQL replication between your live DB and your QA instance.

You will have to configure your prod DB as the master and the QA as the slave. In your prod my.cnf, you will add a "server-id":

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id=1
```

For changes to take effect, you will need to restart the prod DB. Then, update the QA my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
server-id=2
```

Restart the QA DB. Next, create a user on the QA DB for connecting to the master DB and grant it the replication privilege.

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'repl'@'%.mydomain.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'slavepass';
mysql> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'%.mydomain.com';
```

Next, you will need to connect to the prod DB from the command line and run some queries. These will allow you to start the replication process by getting the status of the master database so the slave has coordinates to begin its replication.

```
mysql> FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
```

Leave the session open, then create a new session and run SHOW MASTER STATUS:

```
mysql > SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000003 | 73       | test         | manual,mysql     |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

Write down the file and position. Next, release the lock on master.

```
mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Then, on the slave db, begin replication:

```
mysql> CHANGE MASTER TO
    ->     MASTER_HOST='master_host_name',
    ->     MASTER_USER='replication_user_name',
    ->     MASTER_PASSWORD='replication_password',
    ->     MASTER_LOG_FILE='recorded_log_file_name',
    ->     MASTER_LOG_POS=recorded_log_position;
```

Before doing all of this, make sure you back up all your data on both databases, and if necessary, import a MySQL dump from the Prod DB to the QA DB.

Comment: Are you sure this is possible to do when QA and Live Database is on the same server.

Comment: No, I wouldn't recommend it. My assumption from your question was that the two databases were separate instances.

Comment: What would you recommend ?